# Getting Values from PHP Array

Tags: php, arrays, search, scope

I have the following array:

```
$array = array(1=>'one', 2=>'two', 3=>'three');
```

I know it's possible to use array_search(); to return "1" when searching for "one", but how do I return "one" when searching for "1"?

I've tried $array[1], but this does not work. I'm guessing that's because the array has => in each value, as it normally works without that.

EDIT: Sorry, it was my variable scope.

Comment: I have a feeling that the array you're using is more complicated than the example you gave. You might want to put up a sample of the array you are actually trying to search since Jeremy's answer will give you the desired result on such a simple array.

Comment: You're guessing wrong. => is valid here.

Comment: @vascowhite I did say sorry. If I saw a delete button, I would have deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP's arrays are used to point from keys to values. In your case `1` is a key and `"one"` is a value. You need to use `array_search` when you're trying to get a key from a value, but you're just using an array normally so you can just do:

```
$array[1]
```

Comment: That's what I thought, and I tried it, but it doesn't work. I'm guessing because I have the =>

Comment: @Jack That's very odd. It should, and it [works for me](http://i.stack.imgur.com/WpQGA.png).

Comment: How does it not work? Do you get an error? Show us the code that does not work.

Comment: Hmm... weird. Let me check a few things. Thanks for your help, btw.

Comment: @vascowhite it says I have an undefined variable, but that's not correct. I'm just checking for typos now.

Comment: Edit your question to show the code that doesn't work. Then somebody will be able to help, otherwise its just guesswork.

Comment: Okay, I think the issue is that the variable that's being called is outside of the class and function. It's odd though, because all my other variables can be alled within this class and function :-S

Comment: All fixed, it was the variable scope. Thanks for your help.